# What public domain thesauruses are available?

Tags: resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [English synonym online database?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16939/english-synonym-online-database)

I am working on a project which needs access to the database of a English synonyms, preferably as a raw text file. Are there any public domain, open source, or similarly licensed thesauruses which have a downloadable database and in a simple syntax.

Comment: If you find it, consider adding it to http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2577/13812.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [OpenThesaurus](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openthesaurus/)?

> OpenThesaurus is a PHP/MySQL-based web interface that lets people
>   collaboratively work on a thesaurus. The thesaurus can be exported in
>   many formats like OpenOffice.org, plain text and KWord.

Answer (score 3):

How can a raw text file be anything other than a word list? For it to be a thesaurus, it would have to be indexed, right?

You could download and install [LibreOffice](http://libreoffice.org) and then add [this extension](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/american-british-canadian-spelling-hyphen-thesaurus-dictionaries). Both the office suite and the extension are FLOSS (free/libre open-source software). Note that some users are reporting problems with the extension and at the moment it appears that only US English actually works.

Comment: I just mean, I do not want something downloaded as a binar. I need to be able to construct my own software easily which can access the data.